# Ember-CLI v0.0.44 project not building with a "Use of const in strict mode." error message

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-1

I need to update a template in a fairly outdated ember project (its about 5 years old) but I'm unable to build it.

**Here is the working environment:**

```
Nodejs     v0.10.46 (via NVM)
NPM        v2.15.1
Ember-CLI  v0.0.44
Ember      1.8.1
Bower
```

**Here are the contents of the package.json file:**

```
{
  "name": "xxxxx",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.2.0",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "0.0.17",
    "broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler": "^1.6.1",
    "connect-restreamer": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli": "0.0.44",
    "ember-cli-ember-data": "0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.1.0",
    "express": "^4.8.5",
    "glob": "^4.0.5"
  }
}
```

**Here are the contents of the bower.json file:**

```
{
  "name": "eam-ui",
  "dependencies": {
    "handlebars": "~1.3.0",
    "ember": "1.8.1",
    "jquery": "^1.11.0",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.7",
    "loader": "stefanpenner/loader.js#1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "stefanpenner/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "rwjblue/ember-cli-test-loader#0.0.4",
    "ember-load-initializers": "stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers#0.0.2",
    "ember-qunit": "0.1.8",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.4",
    "qunit": "~1.15.0",
    "foundation": "~5.4.7",
    "ember-i18n": "~2.2.1",
    "cldr": "~1.0.2",
    "es5-shim": "~4.0.1",
    "e164-phones-countries": "~1.0.3",
    "FileSaver.js": "koffsyrup/FileSaver.js"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "^1.11.0"
  }
}
```

**Building the app produces the following output:**

```
ember build
version: 0.0.44

/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/proj1050/xxxxx/node_modules/ember-cli-inject-live-reload/index.js:3
const buildLiveReloadPath = require('clean-base-url');
^^^^^
Use of const in strict mode.
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Function.Addon.lookup (/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/proj1050/xxxxx/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:270:19)
```

I know this project is SUPER outdated.  Any thoughts on what I can do resolve this build issue?   Or should I start planning my escape???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Page output in the browser produces:  Could not find "myProfile.index" template or view.  Nothing will be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is old. :)

You can fix this one particular issue by changing one line in package.json from:

```
"ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.0.2",
```

to

```
"ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.0.3",
```

Good luck.

Comment: Locking down ember-cli-inject-live-reload to version 1.0.3 did help with the build complete.  Thank you.

Comment: Now one of my templates produces this strange message in the Chrome console:  generated -> controller:myProfile.index {fullName: "controller:myProfile.index"}
Could not find "myProfile.index" template or view. Nothing will be rendered {fullName: "template:myProfile.index"}
Transitioned into 'myProfile.index'

Comment: I'd probably need to see your application code to help with this one. Could you accept my answer and post it as another question?